# Is It necessary to normalize Data to generate Natural Splines in Recipes

Tags: r, linear-regression, spline, tidymodels, r-recipes

I fitted a model using natural splines and I am not sure if there are any advantages of using BoxCox and center and scale on the predictors. Does the step natural spline perform the transformations? Are there advantages in normalizing the predictors before natural splines?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)

car <- read_csv('vw.csv')
str(car)
## ---- Split data -----------------------

split <- initial_split(car, prop = 0.80, strata = 'price')
car_train <- training(split)
car_test <- testing(split)


## ---- Recipe --------------------------

rec <- recipe(price ~ . , data = car_train) %>% 
  step_mutate(
    tax = log(tax + 1)
  ) %>% 
  step_ns(mpg, mileage, engineSize, year, deg_free = 3) %>% 
  step_dummy(all_nominal()) 


## -- Model ---------------------------------

model_lasso <- linear_reg(mode = 'regression', penalty = tune(), mixture = tune()) %>% 
               set_engine('glmnet')


## --- Workflow -----------------------------

work01 <- workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(rec) %>% 
  add_model(model_lasso)

## --- Foldes -------------------------------

folds <- vfold_cv(car_train, v = 10, strata = 'price')

## --- tune ---------------------------------

grid01 <- grid_latin_hypercube(parameters(model_lasso), size = 10)

tune01 <- tune_grid(
  work01,
  resamples = folds,
  grid = grid01,
  metrics = metric_set(rmse, rsq)
)

## --- Show_best ---------------------------------

show_best(tune01)
best01 <- select_best(tune01)

## --- Test --------------------------------------

test01 <- work01 %>% 
  finalize_workflow(best01) %>%
  last_fit(split)

test01 %>% collect_metrics()

´´´
```

Comment: I'm quoting this from a Scikit Learn doc "Indeed many estimators are designed with the assumption that each feature takes values close to zero or more importantly that all features vary on comparable scales. In particular, metric-based and gradient-based estimators often assume approximately standardized data (centered features with unit variances). A notable exception are decision tree-based estimators that are robust to arbitrary scaling of the data". https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_all_scaling.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-preprocessing-plot-all-scaling-py

Comment: You **should** center and scale your predictors here, but the reason why is because you are using a regularized regression model. The splines step does _not_ automatically do this. You can check out [recommended preprocessing by model in this Appendix](https://www.tmwr.org/pre-proc-table.html).